# Where to set the PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS value?

Tags: php, apache, mod-fcgid

I have a

> "mod_fcgid ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function"

error in my apache log. Some StackOverflow qnswers suggested I change the PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS value to fix this issue. However I cannot seem to find where this value is to be set(i.e. what file? path?)
I am using LAMP on centos with Plesk panel to maintain.

Comment: please refer to https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/#

Comment: I have an apache server. How do I do it for apache?

Answer (score 0):

Just set FcgidOutputBufferSize to 0 in /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf for fixing this issue.

Comment: I did do that, didn't fix my problem. That's why I am trying this