# Where to set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS value? DUBLICATE

Tags: php, apache, apache2, fastcgi, plesk

I cannot find the location of the conf file where I can change the value of `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS`.
Info about the system: Debian, php7, FAST-CGI, Apache 2.4, Plesk Onyx 17.

There are similar questions on the web including [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668295/where-to-set-the-php-fcgi-max-requests-value), but none of the answers give the file directory.

I need to use this in order to solve the error `(32)Broken pipe..mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function`, as many people recommend to set it 10 times more than `FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

For all Debian-based OSes with Plesk installed, add it to the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` file, inside `IfModule mod_fcgid.c` block:

```
# tail -n 5 /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf
  FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
  FcgidIdleScanInterval 10
  FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500

</IfModule>
```

Do not forget to restart or reload the service:

```
# service apache2 graceful
[ ok ] Reloading web server config: apache2.
```

Comment: I got this error when I add `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS` after `FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500`: Error: `Reloading web server: apache2 failed!
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 26 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf:
Invalid command 'PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything. ... (warning).
`